# SQL code using 'as' resulting in not being able to run

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL microsoft server

I’m quite close with this piece of code… having said that I haven’t got it to run successfully yet… there seems to be issues with me naming ‘tableabc’ (At the end of the first ‘from’).

Ie the line: `WHERE R.PE.d_R_month = (SELECT MAX(d_R_month) FROM R.PE)) AS tableabc`

The error I am getting is: “The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'tableabc'.”

Just for a bit of context, the code does the following:

‘tableabc’ left joins to A.PS table, based on different conditions (As listed).

(I have named the following output as ‘tableabc’. A new column in the R.PAS table is added (and is a summation of the ‘date and month’ creating a column called ‘newdate.’) It then right joins to another table (R.PE) and there are additional conditions applied (ie the maximum dates are only shown)

```
Select

    A.PS.id,

    A.PS.name,

       A.PS.current_phase,

       A.PS.asset_id,

       A.PS.production_category,

       tableabc.*

FROM    

(select R.PAS.*, R.PE.*, DATEADD(month, [R].[PAS].[months_accelerated], [R].[PE].[d_date]) as 'newdate'

 
from R.PAS

Right join R.PE

On [R].[PAS].[id] = [R].[PE].[id]
 
    WHERE R.PE.d_R_month = (SELECT MAX(d_R_month) FROM R.PE)) AS tableabc

    LEFT JOIN A.PS

    ON tableabc.id = A.PS.id

    Where A.PS.prod = 'Include' OR A.PS.R_category <> 'Can' or A.PS.R_category <> 'Hold';
```

Comment: try Right join R.PE  AS tableabc
    On [R].[PAS].[id] = [R].[PE].[id] and R.PE.d_R_month = (SELECT MAX(d_R_month) FROM R.PE))
or use cross apply even better ;)

Comment: You should list columns in your `SELECT` statements explicitly, instead of using `*`, as in result you have conflicts between `id` columns of joined tables

Comment: @d00lar thanks for your message - for some reason for i'm getting quite a few more errors... 'left join' towards the end (saying 'incorrect syntax near 'left, expecint 'as, for, path, id)... and then for ON tableabc.id = A.PS.id  ... i get tableabc.id  with an error saying names are declutted

Comment: @alexey, thanks for your help too! This is a good point :) It didn't quite solve the problem, but i appreciate your help :)

Comment: you canot have 2 times FROM   also. it is hard to solve this without real data. prepare real example with some @temp tables with fake data - will be a lot easier to help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example